# How to store/organize DDL script?

Tags: sql, ddl, organization

First of all, I'm using MySQL on the cloud ( Amazon RDS ). My database definition script has statements to create views, triggers, stored procedures, users, grant permissions to users plus insert some data (e.g look-up tables ) etc. This script has 2000 lines of SQL code. I keep this script in just one file and I execute it using : mysql --user=myusername --password=mypassword  << my.script.sql. This file is protected by SVN.

The issue with having all the SQL code in one file is that it's difficult to see the SVN history for just one item ( say I want to see the SVN history for the table Task and the view TaskView ).... So my question is : how do people store such scripts ? Do professional people store each item ( table,view,stored procedure ) in its own file in a directory ? If so , one has to make a script that deploys all the mini SQL scripts in a folder ? Do people just make a script that looks for every .SQL file and dumps it on the DB ? Do people use various folders to organize such a script ? E.g one folder for views, one folder for tables, one folder for stored procedures ?

Cheers !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have following folder structure

```
+ddl
....group1_ddl.sql
....group2_ddl.sql
+procedures
---level1
......single_sp.sql
......another_sp.sql
---level2
......another_uses_level1_sp.sql
---leveln
......remaining_sp.sql
+views
--level1
......group_of_views.sql
```

As you can see we have 3 top level folders, each for ddl, sps and views

**DDL**

90% of time we have one ddl script for all the tables
Some times we mainitain ddl scripts separately which can be separated logically
ex: staging_ddl.sql, aggrigate_ddl.sql
ddl script includes PK and FK constriants and also additional indeces

**Stored Procedures**

1. Note the multiple folders (level1, level2), since our our entire ETL
   & business is implemented in stored procedures so we have lot of sps
   (dozens) with hundreds of lines of code. Since we are wrote modular
   coding we have some sps depending on other sps. So the sps which
   depend on other sps go to higher level

   ex: In our scenario main_sp.sql is one sp which runs the entire workflow, this sp intern calls rest of the sps in the sequential order and they intern may or may not call other sps
2. so main_sp.sql goes to the level3, child_sp.sql goes to level2,
   grand_child_sp.sql goes to level1
3. file name is same as sp name

**Views:**

1. If your views are less complex and you think you can maintain easily
   you can manage them in a single script.
2. But in our case they are some views with nearly over 2000 lines so
   we maintained them in one script per view.
3. Mostly we try to avoid using a view in another view, in case we did
   it then we maintain the multiple level hierachy as explained above
   otherwise we maintain single script per view
4. file name is same as view name

This is how I have been managing the scripts successfully since over 7 years.

Hope this helps

Comment: the "Level 1", "Level 2" etc. idea is such a brilliant idea ! ;-) OK One question for you : how do you "execute" the scripts ? Do you have a bash script that picks up all the scripts in all subdirectories etc ? Or do you use some other tool ? BTW - I really appreciate this - Cheers !

Comment: thats another question :) anyway I do use them unofficially (to buy extra time ;)) to build the entire script. I have written batch file (type command), perl script (to interact with my version control software) to do that.